# JBoss console doesn't contain details of "The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request"

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces, jboss7.x

I'm using spring security, jsf-2, in JBoss 7.1.1 Final. When an exception is thrown, all I'm seeing in the browser is this:

> The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from
>   fulfilling this request.

When I check the JBoss console, I don't get any output regarding the error.
Where can I find the error details?

Here is the code that's failing:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<ui:composition template="../../base/template.xhtml">
  ...
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

If i deleted the whole ui:composition tag it renders the page but empty.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
</html>
```

output would be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head></head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Any idea how to log the thing? i've turned on logs on like so:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
    <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
        <level name="FINE"/>
        <formatter>
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
        </formatter>
    </console-handler>
    <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE">
        <formatter>
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
        <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <append value="true"/>
    </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
    <logger category="com">
        <level name="FINE"/>
    </logger>
    <logger category="org">
        <level name="FINE"/>
    </logger>
    <logger category="java">
        <level name="FINE"/>
    </logger>
    <root-logger>
        <level name="FINE"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
            <handler name="FILE"/>
        </handlers>
    </root-logger>
</subsystem>
```

Comment: Could not be found in the server logs. Any ideas why?

Comment: You're sure nothing failed during the deployment of your application?

Comment: got this Failed to start service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: Address already in use: bind /127.0.0.1:9990
but i think it's not serious, i'm not using anything in it..
i've turned the logging level to FINE

Comment: also:
[org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-11) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to exception: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011054: Could not find default constructor for class org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that this page had a dependency toward a jsf managed bean that had a dependency towards a spring managed beans that was mis-programmatically configured with an @Autowired that wasn't provided a getter setter to it and was referencing no where.

The thing is, why JSF did not report the error when it couldn't resolve the el expression that referenced the problematic jsf managed bean and why spring did not complain about it is beyond me.